# php-error body class in admin after updated wordpress 5.6.2 to 5.7 via docker pull wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, docker-compose

This is such a strange problem.

I have updated from wordpress `5.6.2` to `5.7` using docker compose for my local environment by...

1. `docker-compose down` - to stop and remove current running environment
2. `docker pull wordpress` - to pull the latest 5.7 image from docker hub
3. `docker-compose up -d` - to rebuild the environment using my existing persistent data.

The update seemed to go well, logged into the admin dashboard, and the update was running.

But I noticed this strange white gap like there was an error but no printed error.

One of my projects regular wp installation...

[image]

And same problem on another of my projects but running in multisite mode...

[image]

This white space below the `#wpadminbar` is caused by `php-error` class in the body tag in the admin dashboard...

[image]

But there is no error outputted. Why could this be and how can I debug the error if no error is displayed?

Unfortunately I've had roll back to the previous wordpress image `5.6.2` changing this in my yml...

```yml
  # here is out wordpress container
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.6.2
    volumes:
```

And then the non existent `php-error` admin body class goes away.

---

I've tried viewing error logs using...

```yml
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

  define('WP_DEBUG', true);
  define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

And then dockering up, and running the site admin to fire the error, then checking wp-content for the error log...

```txt
joshmoto@Joshs-iMac thesweetpeople % docker-compose exec wordpress /bin/sh
# ls
index.php    wp-activate.php     wp-comments-post.php  wp-config.php  wp-includes        wp-login.php     wp-signup.php       xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-admin            wp-config-docker.php  wp-content     wp-links-opml.php  wp-mail.php      wp-site-switch.php
readme.html  wp-blog-header.php  wp-config-sample.php  wp-cron.php    wp-load.php        wp-settings.php  wp-trackback.php
# cd wp-content 
# ls
cache  index.php  mu-plugins  plugins  themes  uploads
#
```

As you can see no error log is being created.

---

I'm outputting logs now successfully but persistent mapping logs to my project using error-logging.ini...

```yml
      - ./logs:/var/www/html/wp-content/logs
      - ./error-logging.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
```

```ini
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/www/html/wp-content/logs/debug.log
```

I've actually tested this by creating errors and running them, logs are working. But there is no log for this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the error log yet?

Comment: @cabrerahector I couldn't find one https://i.imgur.com/1D9vTWq.png theres noting located in any of these folders

Comment: Have a look at the Apache/nginx log, if there were any PHP error/notice messages they should be logged there. Alternatively: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: @cabrerahector Yeah i'm running images mysql:5.7 and wordpress so not sure how to see the apache nginx log, I tried creating my own log last night using `WP_DEBUG_LOG` but it wasnt getting outputted to `wp-content/debug.log`. It's like there is no actual error. I know there are no errors in my theme code and plugins. If I revert back to 5.6.2 the error disapears.

Comment: @cabrerahector see update to end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally figured it out the issue, I think. Now error is gone now and I have 5.7 running error free.

First I went to the docker mac app, went to images, click the 3-dot dropdown on wordpress latest image (5.7) and pulled the latest updates for the image. This may have fixed it, not sure.

I was also defining `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in extra configs and defining `WORDPRESS_DEGUG: 1` in `environment:`.

Which may have cause the error because WP_DEBUG was being defined twice.

These two changes seem to have fixed the issue.