# Enabling Wordpress debug mode in docker-compose environment

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having problems understanding how to enable wordpress debug mode through docker-compose.
[image of wp-config.php debug section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMS8I.png)

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', !!getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DEBUG', '') );
```

This is the part of the wp-config.php file where I should be able to enable it.
The file is read only and it seems to be designed to enable this feature through docker-compose.yaml file but I cant figure out how.
I have tried adding `WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 'true'` to the environment section of wordpress service but it throws error with true/fals data type and 'true' as a string does not seem to work.
The only solution I can come up with is to edit the file as superuser.

Comment: Can you try setting `WORDPRESS_DEBUG` to `1` or `0`?

Comment: Unfortunately does not change anything. Figured I'd chmod 777 the whole project and change it manually since it's only a localhost project for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok this tripped me up big time a year or so ago. See my original problem [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660268/php-error-body-class-in-admin-after-updated-wordpress-5-6-2-to-5-7-via-docker-pu) which led onto `wp_debug` mode being defined twice causing a constant blank php error in the admin...

[php-error body class in admin after updated wordpress 5.6.2 to 5.7 via docker pull wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660268/php-error-body-class-in-admin-after-updated-wordpress-5-6-2-to-5-7-via-docker-pu)

A few rules when using `wp_debug` with the [docker wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) image.

1. You cant use `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in the `wp-config.php`/`WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` and `WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1` in the `docker-compose.yml` at the same time. Using them simultaneously will always give you a blank php error in the admin dashboard.
2. When deploying wordpress with docker using `docker-compose.yml` to configure your environment, you should never really have to manually change the permissions of your project using `chmod 777` to make debug mode work.
3. You should never edit your core wordpress docker container files either, all environment configs should be done through your `docker-compose.yml` file, so that you can spin up and update your docker wordpress container image safely.

So now we know these basic rules, this is how to enable `WP_DEBUG` in `docker-compose.yml` the right way. See the environment block.

> Please note if you try to spin up my example `docker-compose.yml` you
> must also have `uploads.ini` and `error-logging.ini` files present in
> the same directory before running `docker-compose up -d`.

See public [gist](https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/ab7c09ca45291f7e6f9a14cf070fa70c) here which has the `.ini` files code which you need to implement before dockering up...

https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/ab7c09ca45291f7e6f9a14cf070fa70c

Your empty project directory should like this...

[image]

Here is the full `docker-compose.yml` config...

```yml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:

  # here is our mysql database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress server
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - ./themes/yourtheme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/yourtheme:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./logs:/var/www/html/wp-content/logs
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./error-logging.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:

      # debug mode
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1

      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb

      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');

        /* do not re-define WP_DEBUG here or it will throw a blank error in the admin */
        /* you can remove this entirely, this is just to show you what not to do */
        // define('WP_DEBUG', true);

        if (!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }
```

Now you have this `docker-compose.yml` set, along with the `.ini` files, you can now safely run this command in your project directory to build your local wordpress environment...

```txt
docker-compose up -d
```

This `docker-compose.yml` example also uses persistent volume mapping to your project directory, so once docker has finished building your environment, your local project directory will now look like this...

[image]

If you now visit http://localhost/ after initial dockering up has finished, you will now see the install page...

[image]

Error log files will be saved to your `logs` directory and all other necessary wordpress directories are now mapped to your local project.

So next time you run `docker-compose down` and then re-run `docker-compose up -d`, your local environment will be exactly the same as when you last dockered down.

If you are using git, then you will probably want to exclude heavy directories such as `db`, `plugins`, `uploads`, `logs` etc using a `.gitignore` file...

```txt
/db
/plugins
/uploads
/logs
```

I have also added `.gitignore` to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/ab7c09ca45291f7e6f9a14cf070fa70c).

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: This is generally a really helpful example of how to get started developing locally with WordPress' docker image.  Thanks!